# modulo instalado pero no encontrado por el editor de codigo. python

Tags: python, python-3.x, librería, modulos

instale la libreria de el libro "automate boring stuff whit pithon" (si, apenas estoy empezando en esto). aun no utilice ningun modulo de la libreria, estoy intentando importar en la primera linea de codigo un modulo con "import pyperclip" y me arroja "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip'". para aclarar ya revise mil veces y esta bien escrito el nombre del modulo, no lleva mayusculas ni nada.

estoy usando python 3.10.5 en MUcode, windows 10.

muchas gracias de antemano, me serivira mucho poder dejar de renegar con esto y poder avanzar con mi proyecto.

Comment: Pareciera que estás importando correctamente el modulo. Se que es un poco tonta la pregunta que voy a hacer. Pero seguro que instalaste el modulo? Otra cosa, cuantas versiones de Python tenés instaladas?

Comment: si, revise en el 'power shell' y esta instaladisimo, me fije recien igual que la libreria este instalada y tambien lo esta. solo tengo la version de python que mencione ahi. muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

al final con "pip install --user biblioteca que buscas " en el powershell al final te dice la direccion en la que esta instalada la bilbioteca y con

import sys
sys.path.append('direccion de donde esta la bilbioteca')

pude forzar al amulador a quebusque tambien en esa direccion y encuentre los modulos en la biblitoeca

Comment: Con Pycharm la vida se te hace mucho más fácil: puedes revisar e instalar módulos "oficiales" desde dentro del IDE.

Comment: Ya hicistes está pregunta, Elimina una de las dos para no tener preguntas repetidas.}